# Tuning with classification_cost and custom cost matrix in Tidymodels

Tags: r, performance, tidymodels, yardstick

I am using tidymodels for building a model where false negatives are more costly than false positives. Hence I'd like to use the `yardstick::classification_cost` metric for hyperparameter tuning, but with a custom classification cost matrix that reflects this fact.

Doing this after fitting a model is simple enough:

```r
library(tidymodels)

# load simulated prediction output
data("two_class_example")

# cost matrix penalizing false negatives
cost_matrix <- tribble(
  ~truth, ~estimate, ~cost,
  "Class1", "Class2",  2,
  "Class2", "Class1",  1
)

# use function on simulated prediction output
classification_cost(
  data = two_class_example,
  truth = truth,
  # target class probability
  Class1, 
  # supply the function with the cost matrix
  costs = cost_matrix)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   .metric             .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>               <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 classification_cost binary         0.260
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

But using this function during hyperparameter tuning is where I run into problems. [The documentation](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/reference/metric_set.html) states that for setting options the metric should be wrapped in a custom function. Here's my attempt and the resulting error. Note how this wrapper works fine for evaluating a fitted model, but throws an error when trying to use for tuning:

```r
library(tidymodels)

# load data
data("two_class_example")
data("two_class_dat")

# create custom metric penalizing false negatives 
classification_cost_penalized <- function(
  data,
  truth,
  class_proba,
  na_rm = TRUE
) {
  
  # cost matrix penalizing false negatives
  cost_matrix <- tribble(
    ~truth, ~estimate, ~cost,
    "Class1", "Class2",  2,
    "Class2", "Class1",  1
  )
  
  classification_cost(
    data = data,
    truth = !! rlang::enquo(truth),
    # supply the function with the class probabilities
    !! rlang::enquo(class_proba), 
    # supply the function with the cost matrix
    costs = cost_matrix,
    na_rm = na_rm
  )
}

# Use `new_numeric_metric()` to formalize this new metric function
classification_cost_penalized <- new_prob_metric(classification_cost_penalized, "minimize")

# test if this works on the simulated estimates
two_class_example %>% 
  classification_cost_penalized(truth = truth, class_prob = Class1)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   .metric             .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>               <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 classification_cost binary         0.260

# test if this works with hyperparameter tuning

# specify a RF model
my_model <- 
  rand_forest(mtry = tune(), 
              min_n = tune(),
              trees = 500) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

# specify recipe
my_recipe <- recipe(Class ~ A + B, data = two_class_dat)

# bundle to workflow
my_wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(my_model) %>% 
  add_recipe(my_recipe)

# start tuning
tuned_rf <- my_wf %>% 
  # set up tuning grid
  tune_grid(
    resamples = vfold_cv(two_class_dat, 
                         v = 5),
    grid = 5,
    metrics = metric_set(classification_cost_penalized))
#> i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry
#> x Fold1: internal: Error: In metric: `classification_cost_penalized`
#> unused argum...
#> x Fold2: internal: Error: In metric: `classification_cost_penalized`
#> unused argum...
#> x Fold3: internal: Error: In metric: `classification_cost_penalized`
#> unused argum...
#> x Fold4: internal: Error: In metric: `classification_cost_penalized`
#> unused argum...
#> x Fold5: internal: Error: In metric: `classification_cost_penalized`
#> unused argum...
#> Warning: All models failed. See the `.notes` column.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Unnesting the notes shows that there are unused arguments: `"internal: Error: In metric:` classification_cost_penalized`\nunused arguments (estimator = ~prob_estimator, event_level = ~event_level)"` But apparently the `yardstick_event_level()`function, which is how `event_level` should be set according to [this documentation](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/reference/classification_cost.html), does not exist? No function under that name shows up when searching for it.

I don't know how to proceed here.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are tweaking an existing yardstick metric, it is much easier to use the `metric_tweak()` function, which allows you to hard code certain optional arguments (like `cost`), while keeping everything else the same. It is sort of like `purrr::partial()`, but for yardstick metrics.

```r
library(tidymodels)

# load data
data("two_class_example")
data("two_class_dat")

cost_matrix <- tribble(
  ~truth, ~estimate, ~cost,
  "Class1", "Class2",  2,
  "Class2", "Class1",  1
)

classification_cost_penalized <- metric_tweak(
  .name = "classification_cost_penalized",
  .fn = classification_cost,
  costs = cost_matrix
)

# test if this works on the simulated estimates
two_class_example %>% 
  classification_cost_penalized(truth = truth, class_prob = Class1)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   .metric                       .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>                         <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 classification_cost_penalized binary         0.260

# specify a RF model
my_model <- 
  rand_forest(
    mtry = tune(), 
    min_n = tune(),
    trees = 500
  ) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

# specify recipe
my_recipe <- recipe(Class ~ A + B, data = two_class_dat)

# bundle to workflow
my_wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(my_model) %>% 
  add_recipe(my_recipe)

# start tuning
tuned_rf <- my_wf %>% 
  tune_grid(
    resamples = vfold_cv(two_class_dat, v = 5),
    grid = 5,
    metrics = metric_set(classification_cost_penalized)
  )
#> i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry

collect_metrics(tuned_rf)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 8
#>    mtry min_n .metric              .estimator  mean     n std_err .config       
#>   <int> <int> <chr>                <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>         
#> 1     1    35 classification_cost… binary     0.407     5  0.0162 Preprocessor1…
#> 2     1    23 classification_cost… binary     0.403     5  0.0146 Preprocessor1…
#> 3     1    10 classification_cost… binary     0.403     5  0.0137 Preprocessor1…
#> 4     2    27 classification_cost… binary     0.396     5  0.0166 Preprocessor1…
#> 5     2     6 classification_cost… binary     0.401     5  0.0161 Preprocessor1…
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I wasn't even aware of this kind of approach. Maybe you could reference this in the documentation as well? 
Also, do you have an idea why the metric works for evaluating a fitted model, but not for tuning in the example I posted? Still curious about this. 

Either way, thank you for commenting and making this approach clear.

Comment: Using the example code & data, I get and error `Error in value[[3L]]():
! In metric: classification_cost_penalized
object cost_matrix not found` with tune_grid function.

Comment: @ayasugihada Using quasiquotation solved the issue for me. Inside of `metric_tweak`, I changed `costs = costs_mtx` to costs = !!costs_mtx`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an alternative metric or approach you would recommend for a situation in which costs are different? It doesn't seem to do a whole lot for evaluating what is best, even when extreme differences between false positives and negatives are provided. An example based on your code above:

```
library(tidymodels)

# load data
data("two_class_example")
data("two_class_dat")

cost_matrix_1 <- tribble(
  ~truth, ~estimate, ~cost,
  "Class1", "Class2",  10,
  "Class2", "Class1",  1
)

cost_matrix_2 <- tribble(
  ~truth, ~estimate, ~cost,
  "Class1", "Class2",  1,
  "Class2", "Class1",  10
)

classification_cost_penalized_1 <- metric_tweak(
  .name = "classification_cost_penalized_1",
  .fn = classification_cost,
  costs = cost_matrix_1
)

classification_cost_penalized_2 <- metric_tweak(
  .name = "classification_cost_penalized_2",
  .fn = classification_cost,
  costs = cost_matrix_2
)

# test if this works on the simulated estimates
two_class_example %>% 
  classification_cost_penalized_1(truth = truth, class_prob = Class1)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   .metric                       .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>                         <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 classification_cost_penalized binary         0.260

two_class_example %>% 
  classification_cost_penalized_2(truth = truth, class_prob = Class1)

# specify a RF model
my_model <- 
  rand_forest(
    mtry = tune(), 
    min_n = tune(),
    trees = 500
  ) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

# specify recipe
my_recipe <- recipe(Class ~ A + B, data = two_class_dat)

# bundle to workflow
my_wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(my_model) %>% 
  add_recipe(my_recipe)

# start tuning
tuned_rf <- my_wf %>% 
  tune_grid(
    resamples = vfold_cv(two_class_dat, v = 5),
    grid = 50,
    metrics = metric_set(classification_cost_penalized_1,classification_cost_penalized_2)
  )
#> i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry

#seems to always be increasing or decreaing and not much differrence even when large differences
collect_metrics(tuned_rf) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = min_n, y = mean, color = .metric)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(rows = "mtry")
```

[visualization of metrics overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrjfO.png)